# Svg path not closing correctly

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a bridge-like shape with an svg using javascript. With the following html I get the overall shape, but the close path is wrong:

```html
<svg height="897" width="414" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 414 897">
    <path stroke-width="3" stroke="blue" style="fill:transparent; fill-opacity: 1" 
        d="M 0 0 V 207 H 30 
           M 30 207 q 0 -177 177 -177 
           M 207 30 q 177 0 177 177 
           H 414 V 0 H 0 z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

This produces the following shape: [image]

It is closing in a strange way which means that it isn't filling correctly. The strange vertical line from the top of the arch to the top left shouldn't be there. How do I get it to close properly and fill properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path will close from your last point to the last declared `M`. You can fix this by removing all the `M` calls except the first one. Since you are making a continuous line you don't need to move to a new point every time.

```html
<svg height="897" width="414" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 414 897">
    <path stroke-width="3" stroke="blue" style="fill:transparent; fill-opacity: 1" 
        d="M 0 0 V 207 H 30 
           q 0 -177 177 -177 
           q 177 0 177 177
           H 414 V 0 H 0 z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: This removes the weird line visibly, but if I add a fill to the path then you can see it is still there, and it doesn't fill correctly

Comment: @joshuajackson i made an edit to the snippet. Check it out, it now also works if you fill the svg